# How to estimate quantile regression predictions in R

Tags: r, regression

I have a matrix with p>>n, so I use

```
X=mvtnorm::rmvnorm(300,mean=rep(0,400)) 
Y=X[,3]+X[,5]+X[,7]+X[,9]
fit1 = quantreg::rq.fit.lasso(y=Y,x=X,tau=0.5)
```

How can i make predictions based on this? If i use the standard predict I get:

`Error in UseMethod("predict") : 
  no applicable method for 'predict' applied to an object of class "list"`

Comment: What happens if you call the predict function from the `quantreg` package?

Comment: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/quantreg/quantreg.pdf

Comment: `Error in UseMethod("predict") : 
  no applicable method for 'predict' applied to an object of class "list"`

Comment: In that case it would be good to have a reproducable example with data etc.

Comment: `fit1` contains the coefficients in `fit1$coefficients`. You could make a prediction "by hand" using the coefs.

Comment: I have added reproducible code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at `?quantreg::rq.fit.lasso`, I find the following statement:

> Value
>
> Returns a list with a coefficient, residual, tau and lambda
>   components. When called from "rq" **(as intended)** the returned object
>   has class "lassorqs".

Emphasis is mine. Trying this out as

```
library(mvtnorm)
library(quantreg)

set.seed(42)
X = mvtnorm::rmvnorm(300,mean=rep(0,400))
Y = X[,3]+X[,5]+X[,7]+X[,9]
df <- data.frame(Y, X)
cj = quantreg::rq(Y ~ ., tau=0.5, data = df, method = "lasso")

preds <- predict(cj, df)
head(preds)
         1          2          3          4          5          6 
 4.2973424  0.9515407 -0.2925830 -0.7729388  3.0123608 -3.9507194
```